# =IF(AND in Excel with Text condition in different table

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I'm using excel to create an if else condition. I have two excel sheets with different information. Later I want to migrate this to MS Access. My condition looks like this:

`=IF(AND(Table2[delivered]="yes"; (Table2[Delivered2]="yes"), "yes", "no")`

I always get an error while executing. Can somebody tell me where I made a mistake? I checked several MS Excel tutorials for condition and this is how it must look like.

Comment: Hi, the expression you shared, does not explain clearly what you want to achieve, is the expression in Ms Access  or excel, what error are you getting,what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You have to use either semicolons (German) or commas (English) within the formula to separate the formula parts: `=IF(AND(Table2[delivered]="yes"; (Table2[Delivered2]="yes"); "yes"; "no")` or `=IF(AND(Table2[delivered]="yes",(Table2[Delivered2]="yes"), "yes", "no")`

Comment: You are mixing semicolons and commas, you should use only one of them.

Comment: Also using a `(` too much : `=IF(AND(Table2[delivered]="yes",Table2[Delivered2]="yes"), "yes", "no")` or `=IF(AND(Table2[delivered]="yes";Table2[Delivered2]="yes"); "yes"; "no")`